# Zapier identifying JSON data as string

Tags: json, zapier

My question is how can I pull the values for events.payload.media.name?

I am posting to a raw zapier webhook from another app. If I check it using requestb.in it comes through as "Content-Type: application/json". The output is also validating as JSON.

```json
{
   "hook":{
      "uuid":"1asdfasd5-asdf-4f52-bd31-c7a544897808"
   },
   "events":[
      {
         "uuid":"0asdfasdfasdf0",
         "type":"viewing_session.turnstile.converted",
         "payload":{
            "visitor":{
               "id":"28b606b_7853753-3868-4f07-9543-70da084452cc-7442322af-407bdc31d8fc-2739"
            },
            "viewing_session":{
               "id":"154284_b40c5358-1faf-40e9-a44e-60aa641a11cd-fd3c69d8d-302471c603f4-8245"
            },
            "name":null,
            "media":{
               "url":"https://things.wistia.com/medias/asdfasdf",
               "thumbnail":{
                  "url":"http://embed.wistia.com/deliveries/asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasd.jpg?image_crop_resized=200x120"
               },
               "name":"this is what I want!",
               "id":"asdfasdfasdf",
               "duration":52.872
            },
            "last_name":null,
            "foreign_data":{

            },
            "first_name":null,
            "email":"email@email.com"
         },
         "metadata":{
            "account_id":"asdfasdfasdf"
         },
         "generated_at":"2017-05-02T07:31:08Z"
      }
   ]
}
```

However, when I check the typeof data in the output it is telling me that it is a string (see my code to check below). This prevents me from pulling the info out of it using:

```js
return {stuff: typeof inputData.thing.events.payload.media.name};
```

I'm a huge noob, am I missing something fundamental here?
[screenshot to check typeof data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lpC0.png)

Answer (score 0):

`events` is an array, so you would access it like this:

`inputData.thing.events[0].payload.media.name`

Answer (score 0):

is there a way to have the whole payload without creating a new App in Zapier? inputData didn't work

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the help - It is very much appreciated - but no luck so far.

Both inputData and inputData.thing does return the whole payload (ie the json above) - but the moment I try to access anything below inputData.thing the code returns an error.

This is the error I get if I use an array:
"Bargle. We hit an error creating a run javascript. :-( Error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined "

And the following if I forgo the array:
"Bargle. We hit an error creating a run javascript. :-( Error: 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined"